# Remove the Leaflet zoom control on mobile

Tags: leaflet, mobile

Leaflet includes a simple zoom in/out control on the map, unless [otherwise specified](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-zoomcontrol):

```
zoomControl: Whether a zoom control is added to the map by default.
```

This control is unnecessary on a mobile device, where the device's pinch/zoom gestures work better, but the control is included anyway:

[image]

Is it possible to detect whether the user is on a mobile device, and remove the control if so (while leaving the control in place for desktop users)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the Leaflet documentation, there's [**Browser**](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#browser), *"a namespace with static properties for browser/feature detection used by Leaflet internally"*. More in detail, its **mobile** property is *"true for all browsers running in a mobile device"*.

```
var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: true});
if (L.Browser.mobile) {
   map.removeControl(map.zoomControl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple approach seems to work, using code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

```
//Assume a dekstop device with the zoom control shown
var showZoom = true;

// Test for a mobile device
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 showZoom = false;
}

// specify this option during the map creation
var map = L.map('map',{zoomControl: showZoom})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/slead/Lg6rwzaj/1/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**add this to your code**

```
 map.zoomControl.enable();
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     map.zoomControl.disable();
    }
```